# How can I activate the autocomplete of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I don't know if it's possisbly to have the shortcuts like on VScode, i did the **preferences<editor<content assist and ._@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ** but still i can't use the autocomplete... in the image you can see that the option for `sout` doesn't appear like `System.out.println(c1.getNome())`.

How can I configure that?

[image: sout]

Comment: syso and ctrl+espace not sout

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it on the **Java Editor Templates** preference page.

[image: The unfortunately laid out Java/Editor/Templates preference page.]

Comment: but mine doesn't have to activate, I have too add one by one or can I find like a pack of templates normaly used?

Comment: Not sure I understand--there's already a set of templates included.